# How to reconfigure setTimeout on the fly

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I was wondering if there is a way to set the setTimeout function to different timeout on the fly.

So, for example I check something every 1 second, but if I don't get an expected result in like 10 seconds I want to "reconfigure" this setTimeout to wait 3 seconds instead of 1.

Here is my code:

```
var br = 0;
var waitInterval = 1000;
var sleepInterval = 2000;

var waitForNewRace = setInterval(
function checkForNewRace(){
    if ( $("#data").html() == "1"){        
        $("#res").html("got it!");
    }
    else{
        $("#counter").html(br);
        if (br++ > 9)
            waitInterval = 3000;            
    }                   

    $("#tst").html(waitInterval);
},
waitInterval
);
```

If you want to check it out here is the mentioned code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hitman666/Vyczj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the interval and restart it. See [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/XFgfR/) of your jsfiddle.

EDIT: I've copied your code here in case something happens with your jsfiddle code:

```
var br = 0;
var waitInterval = 1000;
var sleepInterval = 2000;


function checkForNewRace(){
    if ( $("#data").html() == "1"){        
        $("#res").html("got it!");
    }
    else{
        $("#counter").html(br);
        if (br++ > 5){
            clearInterval(waitForNewRace);
            waitInterval += 1000;
            if (waitInterval > 10000)
                waitInterval = 10000;

            waitForNewRace = setInterval(
                 checkForNewRace,
                 waitInterval
            );  
        }
    }                   
    $("#tst").html(waitInterval);
}

var waitForNewRace = setInterval(
    checkForNewRace,
    waitInterval
);
```

Comment: @Kooilnc: thank you! I edited your answer with the jsfiddle code in it.

Comment: Hi @Nikola, that's ok. I won't delete it from jsfiddle though, but you never know about jsfiddles plans.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
var br = 0;

var waitForNewRace = setInterval(function(){
        checkForNewRace();
        if(++br == 9){
            clearInterval(waitForNewRace);
            setInterval(checkForNewRace, 3000);
        }
    }, 1000); 

function checkForNewRace(){
    if($("#data").html() == "1"){   
        $("#res").html("got it!");
        clearInterval(waitForNewRace);
    }else
        $("#counter").html(br);
    $("#tst").html(waitInterval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use clearInterval:

```
var br = 0;
var waitInterval = 1000;
var sleepInterval = 2000;

var waitForNewRace = setInterval(checkForNewRace,
    waitInterval
);    




function checkForNewRace(){
    console.log(waitForNewRace);
    if ( $("#data").html() == "1"){        
        $("#res").html("got it!");
    }
    else{
        $("#counter").html(br);
        if (br++ > 9){
            waitInterval = 3000;            
            clearInterval(waitForNewRace);
            br = 0;


               waitForNewRace = setInterval(checkForNewRace,
    waitInterval
);         
            }
        }                   
    $("#tst").html(waitInterval);
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vyczj/5/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, just need to add two lines to your own code:

```
var br = 0;
var waitInterval = 1000;
var sleepInterval = 2000;

var waitForNewRace = setInterval(
function checkForNewRace(){
    if ( $("#data").html() == "1"){        
        $("#res").html("got it!");
    }
    else{
        $("#counter").html(br);
        if (br++ > 9){
            clearInterval(waitForNewRace);
            waitInterval = 3000;          
            waitForNewRace=setInterval(checkForNewRace,waitInterval);  
        }
    }                   

     $("#tst").html(waitInterval);
   },
   waitInterval
);
```